# How do I write a relevant REGEX pattern to extract sub-string of a larger text string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data` (with lengthy and inconsistent text string notes) and matching IDs. My goal is to extract relevant sub-strings of interest using the `list` of sub-strings and create a new column for the extracted sub-strings. I was told that regex was a good place to start but I'm yet to come up with a good pattern that can produce matching result. I'm hoping that someone see's this and directs me in the right way to solve this.

```
list = ['sentara williamsburg regional medical',
       'shady grove adventist hospital',
       'sibley memorial hospital',
       'southern maryland hospital center',
       'st. mary`s hospital',
       'suburban hospital healthcare system',
       'the cancer center at lake manassas',
       'ucla medical center',
       'united medical center- greater southeast community',
       'univ of md charles regional medical ctr',
       'university of maryland medical center',
       'university of north carolina hospital',
       'university of virginia health system',
       'unknown facility',
       'va medical center',
       'virginia hospital center-arlington',
       'walter reed army medical center',
       'washington adventist hospital',
       'washington hospital center',
       'wellstar health system, inc',
       'winchester medical center']

 data:
     ID     Notes                             
     530.0  Cancer is best diag @Wwashington Adventist Hospital
     651.0  nan
     692.0  GMC-009 can be accessed at ST. Mary`s but not in UCLA Med. Center
     993.0  I'm not sure of Sibley; however, Shady Grove Adventist Hosp. is great hospital
     044.0  nan
     055.0  2015-01-20 was the day she visited WR Army Medical Center in WDC
     476.0  nan
```

Expected output - case really does not matter!

```
 data_out: 
     ID     Notes                             
     530.0  Washington Adventist Hospital
     651.0  nan
     692.0  ST. Mary`s Hospital, UCLA Medical Center
     993.0  Sibley Memorial Hoapital, Shady Grove Adventist Hospital
     044.0  nan
     055.0  Walter Reed Army Medical Center
     476.0  nan
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Just updated the question with the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: This code runs through all words of the list and compares them to the "Notes" column. If there is a word which is in "list" and also in "Notes", this word will be written in the new column "output". You have to play around with regular expressions to get the desired result. Note:
Due to the fact, that the words in "list" could appear completely different but has the same meaning as the words in "Column" (abbreviations, spelling, mistakes, Csase-sensitive) it whould be difficult to attain all different cases. Thus maybe it whould be usefull to solve this problem with the "bag of word approach"...

```
#Create a new list
newlist=[]

#Split the sentences of the "Notes" column
[newlist.append(data.loc[i,"Notes"].split(" ")) for i in range(len(data["Notes"]))]

#Create the new column "output" and default the values to be the same as in the column "Notes"
data["output"]=data["Notes"]

#Run through all words
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(newlist)):
        for element in range(len(newlist[j])):
            if re.search(newlist[j][element],list[i]):
                data.loc[j,"output"]= "' '{0}".format(newlist[j][element])
```

If there is a more vectorized approach I whould be grateful to comments

Comment: Thanks @user8144295 I'm still having errors ***Invalid Synthax*** at the last for loop: [[data.loc[j,data['Notes']]=list[i] if list[i] in data.loc[j,data['Notes']] for i in range(len(list))]for j in range(len(data['Notes'])) ] If you don't mind, please help me check this out. Thank you again.

Comment: This is awesome. Will try it out and give you feedback in a couple of hours. Thanks @user8144295

Answer (score 0):

I'd do smth. like:

```
import re
reg = re.compile('|'.join(your_list))
results = reg.match(your_data)
```

Comment: reg = re.compile('|'.join(locations))
data['Location'] = data.match(reg) ****Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'match'     Also: reg = re.compile('|'.join(locations))
data['Location'] = data['Notes'].match(reg) ****Error: Series object has no attribute 'match'. How do I fix this. Thank you!

Comment: yes.. sorry.. confused the two... I edited my answer.

Comment: like.. `reg.match(data['Notes'])`

Comment: Got str and byte-like objects errors but used this code ****reg = re.compile('|'.join(locations))
data['Location'] = reg.match(str(data['Notes']).lower()) *** to fix all errors. However, still don't get any matching sub-strings